# fatal: bad revision 'HEAD-1 on revert

Tags: python, git

I want to revert my last commit on a public branch with the commit being pushed up. I wanted to use revert to show what I did wrong and I reverted it, but [these instructions](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/resetting-checking-out-and-reverting/commit-level-operations) are not working:

```
   cchilders:~/work_projects/webapi (ckc/my-branch) 
    $ git revert HEAD-1
    fatal: bad revision 'HEAD-1'
```

Comment: You want `HEAD~1` not `HEAD-1`

Comment: ooo that's right, I remember now. Thanks Reut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To consolidate the answer to this question: The reason why you've received an error is due to syntax error.

The correct instruction would be

```
git revert HEAD~1
```

instead

```
git revert HEAD-1
```